# template function friend of template class with same Type

Tags: c++, class, templates, function

There is apparently an external in teh code below and would be grateful if somebody could point out how it can be avoided.

Thanks

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Ch16, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   
> 1>  p657_b_print.cpp
>   
> 1>p657_b_main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl compare<int>(int &,class Car<int> &)" (??$compare@H@@YAXAAHAAV?$Car@H@@@Z) referenced in function _main
>   
> 1>\na-13\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Ch16\Debug\Ch16.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>   
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

**p657_b.h**:

```
#ifndef P657H
#define P657H

template< class T> class Car; 
template<class T1> void  compare(T1&, Car<T1>&);

template< class T> class Car { 
    friend void  compare<T> (T&, Car<T>&);

private:
    T Wheels;

public:
    Car(): Wheels(4)  {}
    Car(T);
};

#include "p657_b.cpp"
#include "p657_b_print.cpp"

#endif
```

**p657_b.cpp**:

```
#ifndef P643CC
#define P643CC

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include "p657_b.h"

template<class T> Car<T>::Car(T w) {
    Wheels = w;
}
#endif
```

**p657_b_print.cpp**:

```
#ifndef p657_CC
#define p657_CC
#include "p657_b.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void compare(T &iv1, Car<T> &c1) {
    cout << iv1 << endl;
    cout << c1.Wheels << endl;
}

#endif
```

**p657_b_main.cpp**:

```
#include "p657_b.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Car<int> myCar;
    int iv = 5;
    compare(iv, myCar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Normally you shouldn't be including .cpp files into .h files.  .h files usually contain class/functions declarations and inlined/template implementations.  .cpp files contain the rest.  .cpp files should include all .h files they depend on.  .cpp files should be compiled independently, not as part of other .cpp files.

Comment: That is normally true but in case of templates I have read that in the inclusion compilation model you put declarations in .h file and then you include .cc with definitions in the .h as the compiler need to see definitions for any used template

Comment: What is the purpose of two different cpp files for a single header file?

Comment: None I suppose , that is a good point. Let me see if it makes the code work.

Comment: now it works - thanks a lot for this. The code also work by doing what Andrey suggests below. For the moment being I prefer  my way of organising files, i.e.e teh one suggested by Lippman. I may change my mind when I read Stroustrup but my life is already complicated enough by following one author only so I will look at different approaches only after I gain more confidence in what I am doing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whole template definition must be in one file. You should merge `_b.cpp` and `_b.h` and include complete template in your program.

Comment: It **is** sort of in one file.  Everything is included into `p657_b.h`.

Comment: @Andrey in terms of file organization (and everything else) I am following Lippman's book. I had other code organised like the one above and worked alright

Comment: As Stroustrup said you should include template declarations before their use in a translation unit, and compile their definitions separately. In your code templates are in one unit

Comment: @Andrey - can you pelase be more specific. I cant fiollow you. Sorry, I am a beginner. I dont even know what translation unit is supposed to be! It would be great if you could give me an example by referring to the code. Thanks anyaway.

Comment: compiler takes your .cpp files, perform preprocessing (e.g. resolve includes, so all #included files becomes parts of referencing .cpp file) and compiles resulting source files (units) to get object files. Then linker tries to make executable from those object files.

Comment: it looks like `#include "p657_b.h"` in `main` makes no sense because `#define P657H` might be already defined during preprocessing `p657_b.cpp`

Comment: @Aundrey: if i comment out  #include "p657_b.h" in _main compiler doesnt even let me start as Car becomes undefined. Which text would you raccommend to understand how to structure programs into files and know a bit the compilation stage???

Comment: Stroustrup, The C++ Programming Language, chapters 9 "Source Files and Programs" and 13.7 "Templates. Source Code Organization"